# CodeMirror - Is it possible to scroll to a line so that it is in the middle of window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I'm highlighting lines of HTML code in CodeMirror and I want to add an anchor that scroll CodeMirror editor to a given line.

I can scroll to a line X via [setCursor](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) method. But I would like to have the line X in the middle of CodeMirror window. Can I do that? I studied the API and demos but with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialization:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...);
```

Function to show a line in the middle of editor:

```
function jumpToLine(i) {

    // editor.getLineHandle does not help as it does not return the reference of line.
    editor.setCursor(i);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       editor.setLineClass(i, null, "center-me");
       var line = $('.CodeMirror-lines .center-me');
       var h = line.parent();

       $('.CodeMirror-scroll').scrollTop(0).scrollTop(line.offset().top - $('.CodeMirror-scroll').offset().top - Math.round($('.CodeMirror-scroll').height()/2));
   }, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This one should work:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...);

function jumpToLine(i) { 
    var t = editor.charCoords({line: i, ch: 0}, "local").top; 
    var middleHeight = editor.getScrollerElement().offsetHeight / 2; 
    editor.scrollTo(null, t - middleHeight - 5); 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple.

Init:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...);
```

If you want current position to set it later, you can use

```
editor.getScrollInfo();
```

It returns an JavaScript object:

```
{
  "left": 0,
  "top": 0,
  "height": 500,
  "width": 500,
  "clientHeight": 300,
  "clientWidth": 200
}
```

now you can set set editor scroll position using:

```
editor.scrollTo(left,top);
```

Comment: thanks, i was looking for `getScrollInfo()`

Answer (score 3):

You want https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#scrollIntoView

Notice the optional margin parameter which should do what you want:

```
cm.scrollIntoView(what: {line, ch}|{left, top, right, bottom}|{from, to}|null, ?margin: number)
```

Your code would be something like:

```
cm.scrollIntoView({line:50, char:5}, 200)
```